# How to scale Redis Queue

Tags: redis, microservices, message-queue, publish-subscribe, redis-cluster

We are shifting from Monolithic to Microservice Architecture for our e-commerce marketplace application. We chosen Redis pub/sub for microservice to microservice communication and also for some push notification purpose. Push notification strategy is like below:

Whenever an order is created (i,e customer creates an order), the backend publishes an event in respective channel (queue) and the specific push-notification-microservice consumes this event (json message) and sends push notification to the seller mobile.

For the time being we are using redis-server installed in our ubuntu machine without any hassle. But the headache is in future when millions of order will be generated in a point of time then how can we handle this situation ? That means, we need to scale the Redis Queue, right ?

My exact clean question (regardless the above scenario) is:

**How can I horizontally scale Redis Queue instead of increasing the RAM in same machine ?**

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever an order is created (i,e customer creates an order), the
> backend publishes an event in respective channel (queue) and the
> specific push-notification-microservice consumes this event (json
> message) and sends push notification to the seller mobile.

IIUC you're sending a message over Redis PUB/SUB, that's not durable that means if the only producer is up and other services/consumers are down then consumers will miss messages. Any services that are down will lose all those messages that are sent when the said service was down.

Now let's assume, you're using Redis LIST and other combinations of data structures to solve the missing events issue.

Scaling Redis queue is a little bit tricky since entire data is stored in a list, that resides on a single Redis machine/host. What you can do is create your own partitioning scheme and design your Redis keys as per the partitioning scheme as Redis does internally when we add a new master in the cluster, creating consistent hashing would require some efforts.

Very simple you can distribute loads based on the userId for example if userId is between 0 and 1000 then use queue_0, 1000-2000 queue_1, and so on. This is a manual process that you can be automated using some script. Whenever a new queue is added to the set all consumers have to be notified and the publisher will be updated as well.

Dividing based on the number is a range partition scheme, you can use a hash partition scheme as well, either you use a range or hash partitioning scheme, whenever a new queue is added to the queue set the consumers must be notified for potential updates. Consumers can spawn a new worker for the new queue, removing a queue could be tricky as all consumers must have drained their respective queue.

You might consider using [Rqueue](https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue)